# PIVOT with Grand Total

Tags: sql-server

I'm working with PIVOT in SQL, something I've only started learning about this week. I'm trying to get a grand total for each Director as an added column at the side. I've looked online and seen its a popular query, but the ways of doing it seem really confusing and a little over-kill for what I need. Can someone show me how I'd add a grand total column at the end of each row that just adds up the monthly numbers for each Director?

```
 SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT 
        DimDirectoR.Full_Name, YEAR(dim_Date.Date) as [year],left(datename(month,dim_Date.Date),3)as [month], 
        Fact_Stream.Device_Type_ID as Amount
    FROM Fact_Stream INNER JOIN DimDirector ON Fact_Stream.Director_ID=DimDirector.Director_ID 
    INNER JOIN dim_Date 
    on Fact_Stream.Request_View_Date  = dim_Date.ID
) as Directors
PIVOT
(
  COUNT(Amount)
    FOR [month] IN (jan, feb, mar, apr, 
    may, jun, jul, aug, sep, oct, nov, dec)
)AS DirectorsMonthlyStreams
ORDER BY [year], Full_Name
```

Current output:
[image]

I simply want to have a column which says 'Total' at the end of each row displaying the total amount for that directors year...

SQL Server 2012

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just do a sum in the top level select statement:

```
SELECT *, jan+feb+mar+apr+may+jun+jul+aug+sep+oct+nov+dec Total
FROM (
    SELECT 
        DimDirectoR.Full_Name, YEAR(dim_Date.Date) as [year],left(datename(month,dim_Date.Date),3)as [month], 
        Fact_Stream.Device_Type_ID as Amount
    FROM Fact_Stream INNER JOIN DimDirector ON Fact_Stream.Director_ID=DimDirector.Director_ID 
    INNER JOIN dim_Date 
    on Fact_Stream.Request_View_Date  = dim_Date.ID
) as Directors
PIVOT
(
  COUNT(Amount)
    FOR [month] IN (jan, feb, mar, apr, 
    may, jun, jul, aug, sep, oct, nov, dec)
)AS DirectorsMonthlyStreams
ORDER BY [year], Full_Name
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this as well:

[SQL - Pivot with Grand Total Column and Row](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/232181/SQL-Pivot-with-Grand-Total-Column-and-Row)